# Object iteration in reverse (javascript)

Tags: javascript, sorting

How can I iterate over a javascript object, from back to front.

The object looks like this. `{"33":140, "34":100, "35":120, "36":200}`

I want it to display like this...

```
36 | 200
35 | 120
34 | 100
33 | 140
```

I tried sorting first then displaying, but it sorts by the second number, not the key.
How would I either iterate from back to front, or reverse sort based on the key.

I realize this is pretty simple, but Im getting pretty frustrated with it....

Comment: There is no guarantee on the order when you iterate object properties. And you cannot sort objects. I believe you'll have to use an array of objects, and sort that.

Comment: @bfavaretto Correct, objects are not ordered -- but we sure can use the keys, sort them and use that (see my answer).

Comment: @IngoBürk I did, and upvoted your answer. That's indeed the best approach.

Comment: @bfavaretto Yeah, I didn't notice at first that both comments were you. D'oh. :)

Comment: One thing I learned today, objects _are_ ordered, just not in the order they are defined.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A fairly modern version would look like this:

```
Object.keys(obj).sort(function (a, b) {
    return Number(b) - Number(a);
}).forEach(function (current) { 
    console.log(current + ' | ' + obj[current]); 
});
```

Similarly, but with a little bit more code, it could be written for older browsers, too. Or you use shims.

Comment: This is really close to what the OP actually need (`console.log(obj[current])`)

Comment: He wanted to log both. I just thought I wouldn't take all the fun out of it. It solves the actual problem, he can deal with the output.

Comment: Thanks!!...very efficient, and compact.....much better than the solution I was busy cooking up...which relied on alternate arrays, and two loops, in a cumbersome function

Comment: @bfavaretto Since you already wrote the other part, I updated my answer. :)

Comment: The sort may fail if some of the numbers have 1 or 3 digits instead of 2. If that's the case, OP will need to pass a function and do an actual numeric comparison. Then the `.reverse()` could be eliminated as well.