# How do you iterate a JavaScript object in reverse order?

Tags: javascript, object, javascript-objects

I have a nested object containing years and a publication identifier. How do I list the publications by year, latest to earliest? I read [here](https://www.stefanjudis.com/today-i-learned/property-order-is-predictable-in-javascript-objects-since-es2015/) that order of objects is predictable as of ES6. In my code, I have a function that produces a dropdown list of years (addOption) and another that populates a div with the publications for the selected year or all years (populatePubs). If a user selects all years, the publications are presented in order from earliest to latest (ascending), but I want the publications to display in reverse chronological order. Is there a built-in JavaScript object method that can do this?

```js
const testPubs = {
  2019 : {
    '19-6N': {
      'author' : 'jimbo',
      'title' : 'test title'
    },
    '19-7N': {
      'author' : 'jimmy',
      'title' : 'test title 2'
    }
  },
  2018 : {
    '18-6N': {
      'author' : 'joey',
      'title' : 'test title'
    },
    '18-7N': {
      'author' : 'jeffy',
      'title' : 'test title 2'
    }
  },
  2017 : {
    '17-6N': {
      'author' : 'bob',
      'title' : 'test title'
    },
    '17-7N': {
      'author' : 'bobby',
      'title' : 'test title 2'
    }
  },
}

const startYear = 1984;
const currentYear = new Date().getFullYear();

function addOption() { // adds years to dropdown menu
  const select = document.querySelector('#selectYears');
  let blank_option = document.createElement("option");
  blank_option.setAttribute("selected", true);
  blank_option.setAttribute("disabled", true);
  blank_option.textContent = `Year`;
  select.appendChild(blank_option);
  for (let i = currentYear; i >= startYear; i--){
    let option = i;
    let el = document.createElement("option");
    el.textContent = option;
    select.appendChild(el);
  }
  const allYears = document.createElement("option");
  allYears.textContent = `All Years`;
  select.appendChild(allYears)
}
addOption(); // add years dropdown

function populatePubs(year){
  const pubsForYear = document.querySelector("#pubsByYear");
  pubsByYear.class = year;
  while (pubsForYear.firstChild){
    pubsByYear.removeChild(pubsByYear.firstChild);
  }
  if (year in testPubs){
    for (let pub in testPubs[year]){ // add publications for specified year
      let doc = document.createElement("div");
      doc.id = pub;
      doc.textContent = `${testPubs[year][pub].author} - ${testPubs[year][pub].title} - ${pub}`;
      pubsByYear.appendChild(doc);
  }
} else if (year === 'All Years') { // need to ensure order of object is descending
    for (let yr in testPubs){ // add publications for all years
        const yearHeader = document.createElement("h4");
        yearHeader.innerText = yr;
        pubsByYear.appendChild(yearHeader);
      if (typeof testPubs[yr] === 'object'){
        for (let pub in testPubs[yr]) {
          pubsByYear.class = `All Years`;
          const doc = document.createElement("div");
          doc.id = testPubs[yr][pub];
          doc.textContent = `${testPubs[yr][pub].author} - ${testPubs[yr][pub].title} - ${pub}`;
          pubsByYear.appendChild(doc);
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Test Publications by Year</title>
  <body>
  <!-- years dropdown -->
  <select id="selectYears" onchange="populatePubs(this.value)"></select>
  <!-- display current year -->
  <div id="pubsByYear" class="year"></div>
  <script src="script.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Looks like this has already been answered here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18412214/object-iteration-in-reverse-javascript?r=SearchResults&s=1|119.0396 although this is kind of an old post

Comment: var opposite = Object.entries(testPubs).reverse()

Answer (score 1):

You could just use the built in reverse method on arrays in combination with the Object.keys method :

```
function populatePubs(year) {
  const pubsForYear = document.querySelector("#pubsByYear");
  pubsByYear.class = year;
  while (pubsForYear.firstChild) {
    pubsByYear.removeChild(pubsByYear.firstChild);
  }
  if (year in testPubs) {
    for (let pub in testPubs[year]) { // add publications for specified year
      let doc = document.createElement("div");
      doc.id = pub;
      doc.textContent = `${testPubs[year][pub].author} - ${testPubs[year][pub].title} - ${pub}`;
      pubsByYear.appendChild(doc);
    }
  } else if (year === 'All Years') { // need to ensure order of object is descending
    const years = Object.keys(testPubs).reverse();
    for (let yr of years) { // add publications for all years
      const yearHeader = document.createElement("h4");
      yearHeader.innerText = yr;
      pubsByYear.appendChild(yearHeader);
      if (typeof testPubs[yr] === 'object') {
        for (let pub in testPubs[yr]) {
          pubsByYear.class = `All Years`;
          const doc = document.createElement("div");
          doc.id = testPubs[yr][pub];
          doc.textContent = `${testPubs[yr][pub].author} - ${testPubs[yr][pub].title} - ${pub}`;
          pubsByYear.appendChild(doc);
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```